# Which website to ask questions about program environment?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question that has to do with "working your way around a program"?

Here's the question:

> I have 2 monitors (they are different sizes). I'm trying to view and
>   edit the code (HTML, css, JavaScript) in one screen, and have the
>   live/preview window at the second screen. There doesn't seem to be an
>   easy way to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [so]?

Comment: That's for programming, isn't it?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I thought it might fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: I'll try... I just hope it doesn't ruin my rep...

Comment: To reduce any risk of that perhaps start by saying "I think it is OK to ask this here because the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic."

Comment: Here's the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248416/how-can-i-have-the-live-preview-in-its-own-window-in-dreamweaver

Comment: @PolyGeo: Provided you don't put that into the question you ask.  It would be OK in a comment below the question.  The only thing that should go into questions are questions... not meta commentary.

Comment: You're right @RobertHarvey - I'll tighten up on that.  I often remove commentary from Q&As but have not been so strict about preventing it from getting there.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) because its [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says questions about:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

are on-topic